# Upload file with requests module in IronPython

Tags: python, file, upload, python-requests, ironpython

I am trying to upload a file with the following call in IronPython

```
file={'uploadfile': ('data.csv', open("C:/Users/s/Desktop/data.csv",'rb'))}   
print(file) 
res = requests.post(url, files=file)
```

This works in regular Python but in IronPython2.7.5 this throws an error

```
"expected str, got bytes"
```

Any ideas why? thanks!

NeverMind, Used Poster module to perform the upload

```
from poster.encode import multipart_encode, MultipartParam
from poster.streaminghttp import register_openers
import urllib2

register_openers()
items=[]
items.append(MultipartParam.from_file("upfile",   "c:/Users/s/Desktop/data.csv"))    
datagen, headers = multipart_encode(items)
#print("".join(datagen))
req=urllib2.Request(url, datagen, headers)
res=urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

This seems to have a problem with poster not closing the file correctly, so another approach

```
register_openers()
fileObj=open(dataFileLoc, 'rb')
fileData=MultipartParam(name=kfileUpload,filename=fileName,fileobj=fileObj)        
items={kfileUpload: fileData}
datagen, headers = multipart_encode(items)    

req=urllib2.Request(url, datagen, headers)    
res=urllib2.urlopen(req)
fileObj.close()
```

Comment: Quoting from the dupe: *There is an additional problem with requests, an issue with supported encodings (https://ironpython.codeplex.com/workitem/4565) prevents that from working. The issue has been open for ages.*

Comment: Not that I can be certain that that is your issue still; please update the question with a *full* traceback so we can diagnose better.

Comment: i can not post the stack trace as it is has sensitive info. And i see the issue you mention is closed. Is there any other module in ironpython i can use to do this easily? Thanks

Comment: Surely you can just create a sample file makes the same call and produces the same traceback, without any sensitive info? If not, what is different between the two situations to produce a traceback?